# URL rewriting in asp.net 3.5 using query string and without page name

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have implemented the URL rewrite code for asp.net 3.5 with global.asax.

Here is the example. **www.ABC.com/Content/1/Flowers** or **www.ABC.com/Content/1/Balloons**.

Where "Content" is my page name and "Flowers" and "Balloons" are my category.
It is working fine in my case.

Now I want to remove "Content" from my URL. So my URL should be **www.ABC.com/1/Flowers**.

Is it possible in asp.net 3.5 without page name? I didn't use "MVC" architecture in it.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Add("Home", new Route("Home", new WebFormRouteHandler("~/Client/Index.aspx")));
        routes.Add("Content", new Route("{SitepageID}/{name}", new WebFormRouteHandler("~/Client/Content.aspx")));
        routes.Add("FAQ", new Route("FAQ/", new WebFormRouteHandler("~/Client/Faq.aspx")));  
    }
```

Now I want to remove my page names.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx, http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx

Comment: Yes it is possible, show us your rewrite code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use url rewriting based on http module

You can use this method `HttpContext.RewritePath`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath.aspx

Note : You create httpmodule (By implementing IHttpModule) and you register your module

Link of sample : Development/URLrewritingHttpModuleC.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0180_Development/URLrewritingHttpModuleC.htm

Comment: Could you give me the example for more understanding?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0180__Development/URLrewritingHttpModuleC.htm